# Stock market average range of smaller time frames (advanced probability/stochastic processes question)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let's say a stock has an average range of $100 on its daily chart from open to close. The daily chart consists of 390 one minute intervals. Prices can go up or down. Therefore, it can go straight to minus 100 or straight to plus 100. I know the maximum range of a one minute candle is 100, the min size of a one minute candle is 0, and the min size of the max candle is 100/390. However, what would the average range of a one minute interval be? Remember the candles can go positive or negative. It can go from +99 to -1.

I got a MS in Math like 6 years ago and this reminds me of some Brownian motion problems from Stochastic processes. I would like to see the function if possible. Sorry I had to remove $ signs above, it was treating it like an equation.

Comment: The average modeling does not work in the real world. A father 6 ft tall and a son 2 ft tall come across a stream that is 2 ft deep. Since they are on average 4 ft tall, if they decide to walk across the stream, they would have a disaster. 

"Therefore, it can go straight to minus 100 or straight to plus 100." - Why?

There is such a thing called standard deviation and the probability of $7\sigma$ or $9\sigma$ events may be small, but is not zero.

Comment: FWIW, See p.19 Equation 3.11: https://beta.vu.nl/nl/Images/werkstuk-dmouj_tcm235-91341.pdf

That is one such equation

Comment: It can go straight to -$100 or +$100 from the open the first minute and that can be the range on the day. Unlikely, but it's happened. My problem has relevance to other questions.

Comment: It can go more than that also since it is the *average* range. Even if it was a normal distribution, which it is unlikely to be, the average occurs less than 65% of times. That was my point.

Comment: I actually have reasons for searching for this average. It's about looking for moves off of one minute candles. I want to know what I can expect an average one minute candle to be given a daily range though. Maybe I can think of this another way. Think of H or T in coin tosses where H=+1, T=-1, after one toss the average range is 1. After 2, it's 1.5. (1,0 =1), (1,2)=1,(-1,0)=1,(-1,-2 =2), (1+1+2+2)/4=1.5. With 3 it's 2.

Comment: With 4 it's 19/8
1234 (4)
1232 (3)
1212 (2)
1210 (2)
1012 (2)
1010 (1)
10-10 (2)
10-1-2 (3)
Obviously starting with -1 gives a mirror range so 19/8

Comment: So what would my average range be for H=+1 and T=-1, over 390 trials? Hmmm...